# What are bogus file nlink values?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, file-sharing, smb

I am using files from a SMB share on my Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian. Whenever I access those files, I get the following message in my syslog:

```
CIFS VFS: bogus file nlink value 0
```

What does that actually mean, and how do I get rid of it?

The SMB server is an Apple TimeCapsule.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a "bogus" situation where you have a file displayed on a mountpoint, and this file have a number less than one on Inode Links.

Here, is the [cifs structure](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/cifs/cifsglob.h#L1369). `cf_nlink` is the number of inode links a specific file has.

[This piece](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/cifs/inode.c#L584) of code shows that it will fill all information about the files to cifs

```
     if (symlink) {
             fattr->cf_mode = S_IFLNK;
             fattr->cf_dtype = DT_LNK;
     } else if (fattr->cf_cifsattrs & ATTR_DIRECTORY) {
             fattr->cf_mode = S_IFDIR | cifs_sb->mnt_dir_mode;
             fattr->cf_dtype = DT_DIR;
             /*
              * Server can return wrong NumberOfLinks value for directories
              * when Unix extensions are disabled - fake it.
              */
             if (!tcon->unix_ext)
                     fattr->cf_flags |= CIFS_FATTR_UNKNOWN_NLINK;
     } else {
             fattr->cf_mode = S_IFREG | cifs_sb->mnt_file_mode;
             fattr->cf_dtype = DT_REG;

             /* clear write bits if ATTR_READONLY is set */
             if (fattr->cf_cifsattrs & ATTR_READONLY)
                     fattr->cf_mode &= ~(S_IWUGO);

             /*
              * Don't accept zero nlink from non-unix servers unless
              * delete is pending.  Instead mark it as unknown.
              */
             if ((fattr->cf_nlink < 1) && !tcon->unix_ext &&
                 !info->DeletePending) {
                     cifs_dbg(1, "bogus file nlink value %u\n",
                             fattr->cf_nlink);
                     fattr->cf_flags |= CIFS_FATTR_UNKNOWN_NLINK;
             }
     }
```

**Means**: If it´s symlink just set the attributes. If it´s a directory the server can return a wrong number of links when Unix extensions are disabled, then, just mask it with "i don´t know how many nlinks i have" `CIFS_FATTR_UNKNOWN_NLINK` on the client side of Linux CIFS.

However, it could happen that a file have `cf_nlink < 1` and it's not a file with a delete action happening(`!info->DeletePending`) neither have Unix extensions available(`tcon->unix_ext`) than, its weird.  A file with no hardlinks and it´s not being deleted, you will receive the message: `CIFS VFS: bogus file nlink value 0`

I fully understand the situation, but i can´t provide you a fix to this. 
***Maybe*** forcing unix extensions, since you have unix-like on client and on server site could mask the issue.